# convert a local point to a world point

Tags: trigonometry

I can find my local position relative to world space with the following equations:

```
x = X cos A + Y sin A

y = - X sin A + Y cos A
```

Where X and Y are the positions in world space, x and y are the local positions and angle A is the the angle between y and Y.

How do i reverse this and take a local position and make it a world position in the form X = and Y = ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the terms "local position" and "world position".

Think this problem as a linear equation system with variables $X$ and $Y$; consider $x$ and $y$ as a constant number, and solve it. Use the fact $\cos^2 A + \sin^2 A = 1$ to simplify your solution.

Do you know the geometrical meaning of the equations?
When you have the point $(X, Y)$, you can calculate $(x,y)$ by given formula, and it is the rotation transform. ($A$ radian Clockwise rotation) 
So, If you want to have $X =$ and $Y=$ equations, you need to find a $A$ radian counterclockwise rotation formula. (So we get back to the original position.) Simply subsitute $-A$ instead of $A$.

Comment: added a picture world space is the main axis at the top , local space is the axis relative to the objects rotation , and theta is representing A in the diagram

Comment: I see. Try to follow my method.

Comment: Thanks this helped me get to my solution

Answer (score 0):

Add in the offset and transpose the rotation matrix:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
X \\ Y
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(A) & -\sin(A) \\
\sin(A) & \cos(A)
\end{array}
\right] 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x - x_0 \\ y - y_0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: I am unsure of my understanding of your answer , would it be true to say X = (cosA * -SinA)x?

Comment: @BluntInstrument No. Are you not familiar with matrix multiplication?

Comment: nope but i will have a read , was hoping for a X= and Y=

Comment: $X = (x-x_0) \cos(A) - (y-y_0)\sin(A)$ and $Y = (x-x_0)\sin(A) + (y-y_0)\cos(A)$. Matrix notation is just shorthand really.